# .NET Compiler could not find the reference

Tags: c#, .net

I want to use a **third party control** (dll) in a Winforms application. I can integrate the control into the toolbox and then drag and drop it to a windows form. That all works. But during the compilation I get the error message:

**The type or namespace name '....' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)**

The library is also seen below references (solution explorer). But a corresponding "using statement" is missing. I am also not able to add a using...  manually. The Intellisence doesn't provide me the missing item. So what is wrong here?

Comment: Code-behind intellisense can be a bit dicey.  Add the reference namespace anyway, and see what happens.

Comment: Can you try cleaning and building the solution again?

Comment: why the .net tag and what do you mean by code-behind page? isn't it a windows form question as stated "drag and drop it to a windows form"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am 99% sure that the Target Framework of your project is set to .net framework client profile. change it and all will be good.

Comment: This is the solution! I am silly. It's not my day ;-). Thank you!

Comment: @M.X i had the same day, one day...... and that day is no more. Glad it helped. you can accept it then.

Comment: Tbh, not really that silly. I think that have happened to all of us at some point. The difference is how long it takes to go from "This can't be - The compiler must be wrong!" to "Sigh, I give up. Better ask on SO" :)

Comment: the question is why does it creates a client profile project by default.

Comment: @NoOne That is one of life's great mysteries. We never user the client profile in my company and I wish I could change this default behavior.